# Differentiation with Matrix Coefficients and scalar variable.

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I know how to do this for vector variables, and want to make sure it is the same for scalar variables.
Take for example $$f(t)=\frac{\underline{x}^T\textbf{A}\underline{x}}{t}$$ where $\underline{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\textbf{A}$ is an nxn matrix 
, and t is the scalar variable. Is it correct that the derivative is given by $$f'(t)=\frac{-\underline{x}^T\textbf{A}\underline{x}}{t^2}$$ and the second derivative by 
$$f'(t)=\frac{2\underline{x}^T\textbf{A}\underline{x}}{t^3}$$

Comment: Yes. Since $x^TAx$ is constant, it is the same as differentiating $\frac{k}{t}$.

Comment: @bharb What if the coefficient didn't simplify to a scalar? Like just $A$ for example?

Comment: Does the matrix $A$ have fixed coefficients, or are they a function of $t$?

Comment: @bharb I meant fixed but yeah that answers it. Thanks!